# Display decimals with a textview

Tags: android, textview, decimal

Hi i want make so the TextView level can put out decimal but i don'ty know how to do that any one got an idea? NOw it only puts out 1 but i want it to put out 1.80. :)

```
public class Main extends Activity {

int counter;
EditText weight, hours;
TextView amount, level;
Button calcuate;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    counter = 0;
    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
    hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hours);
    amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alcohol_level);
    calcuate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcuate);


    final String widmark = getResources().getString(
            R.string.widmark);
    final String hundra = getResources().getString(
            R.string.hundra);
    final String cl = getResources().getString(
            R.string.cl);

    calcuate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer wid, mgs;

            String w = weight.getText().toString();
            String h = hours.getText().toString();

            wid = Integer.parseInt(w) * Integer.parseInt(widmark) / Integer.parseInt(hundra);
            mgs = Integer.parseInt(cl) / Integer.parseInt(wid.toString()) / Integer.parseInt(hundra);

            level.setText(mgs.toString());
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: You have to use floating point numbers to do the arithmatic, and then use `DecimalFormat` to format the result so desired precision is preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` division will only produce `int`'s.  If you want your output to be of `float` or `double` type, you must use `double` or `float` division.

```
Double mgs;

mgs = Double.parseDouble(cl) / Double.parseDouble(wid.toString()) / Double.parseDouble(hundra);
```

Note that not all variables considered in the expression need to be `double`'s, only one of them does.

Another thing that is noteworthy here is whether or not you want two decimal places (assuming a currency here).  By default, Java/Android will only spit out as many decimal places as necessary.  `1.80` will display as `1.8`.  To alleviate this, you should use a [`NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) (specifically, use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28%29)) so that you can specify that you want the number of decimals for your default `Locale`'s currency.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast anwser :D

Answer (score 1):

Your `mgs` variable is a Integer object. Set it to type float to have decimal places be displayed.

```
float mgs = Integer.parseInt(cl) / Integer.parseInt(wid.toString()) / Integer.parseInt(hundra);
```

I hope this helps.